# C source includes file in some dir (like dir/header.h), but header is in another dir

Tags: c, gcc

Are there any compiler options to deal with it? Without patching sources.

Comment: Create dir and put a symbolic link to the header there ?

Comment: Have you seen the -L option of gcc?

Answer (score 1):

You can tell gcc to look in another include directory with `-I`:

```
gcc -I/home/bob/includes
```

This will add `/home/bob/includes` to the location that gcc searches. Your best bet is to create the tree that gcc is expecting there - for example, if `/home/bob/includes` was the directory where the headers really were, and the code asks for `dir/header.h`, then put the headers in `/home/bob/includes/dir`

Comment: Sure, this is an obvious solution.

My problem is two packages ('a' and 'b'): 'b' uses headers from 'a', but expects 'a' is installed. I'd like to build 'b' when 'a' is not installed.

Comment: You won't be able to build 'b' without the headers of 'a' somewhere that gcc can see - in which case you can use `-I` to tell gcc where you've unpacked 'a', even if it's not installed. You may also need to link against 'a', in which case you'll need `-L` to tell the linker to include libraries from non-standard directories too. Or am I missing something?

Comment: The problem is 'a' has a/header.h, but 'b' wants astuff/header.h.
'a' installs a/header.h as /usr/include/astuff/header.h, but if 'a' is not installed astuff/header.h is not available

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to rewrite include paths at compile time - is there a reason you can't install 'a' somewhere in your home directory?

Comment: Yes, the reason is that 'a' and 'b' are parts of one package and are built at once :-) I'm inclined to restructuring.